# Get all the equipments with or without the last user that borrowed it

Tags: powerbi

I have the following tables:

```
Equipments { id, description }
Loans { id, date, equipmentId, userId }
Users { id, name, login }
```

I need to show all the equipments and the name of the last user that borrowed this equipment. If the equipment has no rows on loans, the equipment still needs to be returned but with a blank user.

I tried using merge query as new, but when I select the users.name column, the number of rows increases, because of the many-to-many relationship.

How can I return only the last user for each equipment or blank?

Answer (score 0):

Is it an SQL solution that you need to get this done in one go? This is definitely non-trivial.
The solution or various attempts at similar are most likely already on here. 
I am no expert, but:
This would need an outer join to make sure that a line is returned where there is no entry in Loans.
You will first need to reduce down Loans to select the max dates for each Equipment ID and only include those rows. I am presuming that there can only be one loan per day? Or you could use Loan ID if this is allocated sequentially.
That should leave you with table containing all of the information apart from the name of the user, which can be obtained through a join and only taking the columns from the result you require.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually I need a solution using DAX or other features from PBI Desktop. Using SQL I can manage to get this working, but the same is not true for PBI :P.